# Android 9patch stretch arrow?

Tags: android, nine-patch

http://www.clker.com/clipart-green-right-double-arrows-set.html

I am struggling to apply 9patch to an image like the one above but with no luck yet. Does anyone know how an arrow can be stretched?? or do you guys know a good tutorial on how to use 9patch with irregular shapes?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such images are meant to be "9-patched". It's mainly intended for stretching the sides of rectangles such as buttons. So my only tip is to use different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9 patch to set the content area of an image, not just how to stretch the outside. So if you plan on placing text inside it to stretch it out, you can define a content area but using a 9patch editor and placing marks on the right and bottom edges. the image outside of this area will just be scaled then. With arrow images, the issue i have is you can't use 9 patch to define a stretchable length along just one edge - a.k.a. a 3-patch image.